# Issue with code, returns `NameError: name 'scraped_grp' is not defined`

Tags: python

When run the script I get this:

```
tsadder.py", line 195, in <module>
keyboard.write('python' + ' ' + program + ' ' + api_id + ' ' + api_hash + ' ' + phone + ' ' + file + ' ' + group + ' ' + str(scraped_grp))
                                                                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'scraped_grp' is not defined`
```

This is the file tsadder.py

```
import asyncio
import csv
import os
import pickle
import platform
import random
import sys
import time

import keyboard
import pyfiglet
from colorama import init, Fore
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PhoneNumberBannedError, PhoneCodeInvalidError, ApiIdInvalidError
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

init()

r = Fore.RED
lg = Fore.GREEN
rs = Fore.RESET
w = Fore.WHITE
cy = Fore.CYAN
ye = Fore.YELLOW
colors = [r, lg, w, ye, cy]
info = lg + '(' + w + 'i' + lg + ')' + rs
error = lg + '(' + r + '!' + lg + ')' + rs
success = w + '(' + lg + '*' + w + ')' + rs
INPUT = lg + '(' + cy + '~' + lg + ')' + rs
plus = lg + '(' + w + '+' + lg + ')' + rs
def banner():
    f = pyfiglet.Figlet(font='slant')
    logo = f.renderText('TG BULK ADDER')
    print(random.choice(colors) + logo + rs)
    print(f'{r}   Version: {w}0.0 {r}| Author: {w}Leonardo Redmond{rs}')


def clr():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')
global scraped_grp
# with open('target_grp.txt', 'r') as f:
#     scraped_grp = f.readline()
# f.close()

clr()
banner()
users = []
input_file = 'members\\members.csv'
with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
        user = {}
        user['username'] = row
        users.append(user)
print(users)
accounts = []
f = open('vars.txt', 'rb')
while True:
    try:
        accounts.append(pickle.load(f))
    except EOFError:
        break
print('\n' + info + lg + ' Creating sessions for all accounts...' + rs)
for a in accounts:
    iD = int(a[0])
    Hash = str(a[1])
    phn = str(a[2])
    clnt = TelegramClient(f'sessions_{phn}', iD, Hash)
    clnt.connect()
    banned = []
    if not clnt.is_user_authorized():
        try:
            clnt.send_code_request(phn)
            code = input(f'{INPUT}{lg} Enter code for {w}{phn}{cy}[s to skip]:{r}')
            if 's' in code:
                accounts.remove(a)
            else:
                clnt.sign_in(phn, code)
        except PhoneNumberBannedError:
            print(f'{phn} {r}is banned!')
            banned.append(a)
        except PhoneCodeInvalidError:
            print(f'{code} is invalid!')
            accounts.remove(a)
        except ApiIdInvalidError:
            print(f' The api_id/api_hash combination is invalid')
            accounts.remove(a)
    for z in banned:
        accounts.remove(z)
        print('\n'+info+lg+'Banned account removed'+rs)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    clnt.disconnect()

print(info+' Sessions created!')
time.sleep(2)
print(f'{plus}{lg} Enter the exact username of the public channel{w}[Without @]')
g = input(f'{INPUT}{lg} User Name[Eg: Techy_Hub]: {r}')
group = 't.me/' + str(g)
#print('\n')
print(f'{info}{lg} Joining from all accounts...{rs}')
for account in accounts:
    api_id = int(account[0])
    api_hash = str(account[1])
    phone = str(account[2])
    client = TelegramClient(f'sessions_{phone}', api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    try:
        username = client.get_entity(group)
        client(JoinChannelRequest(username))
        print(f'{success}{lg} Joined from {phone}')
    except:
        print(f'{error}{r} Error in joining from {phone}')
        accounts.remove(account)
    client.disconnect()
time.sleep(2)
clr()
number = len(accounts)

if number == 0:
    print('please add your accounts using manager.py')
    sys.exit()
print(f'{info}{lg} Total accounts: {w}{number}')
print(f'{info}{lg} If you have more than 10 accounts then it is recommended to use 10 at a time')
a = int(input(f'{plus}{lg} Enter number of accounts to use: {r}'))
to_use = []
print(f'\n{info}{lg} Distributing CSV files...{rs}')
time.sleep(2)

for i in accounts[:a]:
    done = []
    to_use.append(i)
    file = 'members\\members' + str(accounts.index(i)) + '.csv'
    with open(file, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(['username'])
        for user in users[:100]:
            writer.writerow([user['username']])
            done.append(user)
    f.close()
    del_count = 0
    while del_count != len(done):
        del users[0]
        del_count += 1
    if len(users) == 0:
        break
if not len(users) == 0:
    with open('members\\members.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(['username'])
        for user in users:
            writer.writerow([user['username']])
    f.close()
    m = str(len(users))
    print(f'{info}{lg} Remaining {m} users stored in {w}members.csv')
for acc in to_use:
    accounts.remove(acc)
with open('vars.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for acc in accounts:
        pickle.dump(acc, f)
    for k in to_use:
        pickle.dump(k, f)
    f.close()
'''
with open('resume.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(scraped_grp)
    f.close()
'''
print(f'{info}{lg} CSV file distribution complete{rs}')
time.sleep(2)
clr()

program = 'usradder.py'
o = str(len(to_use))
print(f'\n{info}{r} This will be fully automated.')
print(f'{info}{r} Don\'t touch the keyboard until cmd window pop-up stops')
input(f'\n{plus}{lg} Press enter to continue...{rs}')
print(f'\n{info}{lg} Launching from {o} accounts...{rs}\n')
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(random.choice(colors) + str(i) + rs)
    time.sleep(1)
for account in to_use:
    api_id = str(account[0])
    api_hash = str(account[1])
    phone = str(account[2])
    file = 'members\\members' + str(to_use.index(account)) + '.csv'
    os.system('start cmd')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    keyboard.write('python' + ' ' + program + ' ' + api_id + ' ' + api_hash + ' ' + phone + ' ' + file + ' ' + group + ' ' + str(scraped_grp))
    keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
    print(f'{plus}{lg} Launched from {phone}')
```

Comment: You seem to believe that `scraped_grp` actually is defined somewhere.  Where?  There's certainly nothing like that visible in the image you show.  (Not that an image is at all useful here - are you really expecting people to have to retype it all if they want to test a fix to your code?)

Comment: i thy few moves and find -  this x = 0
if x > 10:
    b = 3
print(b)
The IDE reports a problem for print(b). A possible fix is:
x = 0
if x > 10:
    b = 3
    print(b)

Comment: hi brother. thanks for you replay. please. can you first help me to know, how i need to post my question?. i'm really new in this. and really thank you to understand how to do the post. thanks a loot

Comment: maybe this better?  
jasonharper
thank you for your waking me up

Comment: `global` doesn't define variables - it simply tells a function that assignment to that variable goes to the global namespace, not the function namespace. Its useless at global level, so take that line out. `#     scraped_grp = f.readline()` - you've commented out the line that assigns that variable, so not surprising it doesn't work. Uncomment that if you want to use the variable.

Comment: As for posting the question and for debugging in general, make small test scripts that demonstrate the problem. You only need 3 lines of code here. The rest could be deleted without changing the error. That's a huge amount of code and trying to deal with all of it is burdensome. One problem per question and trim out the fluff!